# What would be the minimum height for a complete lap?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

An empty ball, of  mass $m$ and  moment of inertia $I = \frac{2}{3}m.r^{2}$, is rolling across the path shown below:

[image]

there is friction $f_{r}$ from  A to C  .

$r$ is the radius of the ball, and $R$ is the radius of the circular part within the path.

what would be the minimal height $h_{0}$ (in function of $R$) , so that the ball can make a complete lap in the loop (the circular part)?

after applying Newton's 2nd law and some rotational dynamics I found the translational acceleration $a_{T}$ and the friction $ f_{r}$:

$$a_{T}  =  \frac{g.\sin(\alpha)}{\frac{2}{3}r^{2}-1}~~$$

$$f_{r} = \frac{2m.g.\sin(\alpha).r^{2}}{2r^{2}-3}$$

I know that the ball must roll on a distance of $~~ 2\pi R~~$  ( the perimeter of the loop). but I can't figure out how to link between the acceleration and this distance?

Nb: of course the ball is rolling without sliding.

Comment: if there is no friction from B around the loop to C the ball will slide this part of the journey not roll. Why do you state the ball is not sliding when zero friction really means that is exactly what it will do?

Comment: you're right indeed , there is friction all over the path .

Comment: Zero friction doesn't have to slide for a wheel.  In fact for a simple rolling wheel we generally assume no friction.  This just means there's no relative movement between the bottom of the rolling object and the surface it is moving on (i.e. point velocity at the contact is 0).  There can be a coefficient of friction, but it seemed like you wanted it to roll without friction from B to C.  Please clarify.

Comment: no I'am sorry it was just a mistake while I was rewriting the question , as I sad , there is friction all over the path , again I'am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Hilbert Just for some clarity, is this a real life problem, or some simulation?  I'm not sure how to even model friction using a friction coefficient.  You could treat it like a [rolling coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance#Rolling_resistance_coefficient) ; but that would be somewhat of an oversimplification.  The main reason I ask is because this seems like a question that is easier to answer with energy balance; but these friction terms make that more complicated.

Comment: they sad (as a hint in the question) that we can use Newton's law to find a relation between translational velocity and the gravity $g$ , and also we have to consider that the reaction on the top of the loop is zero wich means that there is just gravity on the top of it .

Comment: Did it actually say there was friction in this problem?  I noticed you seemed to be defining the friction yourself.  Was this friction actually in the question or was that just included for you to say it is not sliding?

Comment: no acctually it is included in the problem , because , before this question there was another one wich was asking to express the acceleration , and the friction in terms of mass , radius,..

Answer (score 0):

Look at the situation at the top of the loop when the ball just makes it round the loop. Here the minimum force on the ball from the track is zero - anything less means that the ball has left the track. The net force on the ball is $F=mg$ and its (centripetal) acceleration is $a=v^2/R$ where $v$ is the speed of the CM of the ball. So here you apply $F=ma$.

Then, equating the total mechanical energy of the ball at the top of the loop (linear and translational KE plus PE) with its initial PE at the top of the incline (A) will give you the answer - after you substitute the value of $v$ found above.

I notice there is a sharp turn at B. This implies that there is a *collision* between the ball and the track at this point. Assuming this collision is inelastic (so that the ball does not bounce up from the track) the vertical component of momentum (and therefore also speed) will be lost at this point. You will need to take account of this in your calculation of required height.

Comment: I am very sorry for being late , apparently the solution states that  : $h =\frac{3R}{2} -3r$ I steel can't figure out how did they find that result ,I have tried using enegy conservation but it didn't work too .

Comment: In fact I've found this answer in another very similar problem  they just replaced the sphere with a ring . but I know that the answer  for the sphere should be very similar with the other one above

Comment: Please show your energy conservation calculation.

Comment: Please update your question to include your calculation for conservation of energy.